# Simple JQuery UI variable pass issue (syntax)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, variables

http://jsfiddle.net/danesoul/tSCus/2/ - Here is working example of simple JQuery UI Tabs interface.

Commented string where curent_tab is defined don't work - cause crashing tabs.

Please help me write this syntax correctly.

**General idea of code:** I need to have in my function MySelect()

1. variable which keeps ***index of currently selected tab***
2. variable which keeps ***index of tab which is being selected*** when OnSelect event happens.

There is part of more complex solution, which is strongly need these two values for future compare.

***Copy of jsfiddle JS code here:***

```
function MySelect(event, ui){
    var clicked_tab = ui.index //new clicked tab 0-1-2 indexes
    alert(clicked_tab); 
    alert(curent_tab +' / '+ clicked_tab);     
}

$(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        //var curent_tab = ui.index; //befor new one clicked 0-1-2
        select: function(event, ui) {
            MySelect(event, ui);
        }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly you want to get the current tab and clicked tab. Try below code,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/tSCus/4/)

```
$(function() {
    var current_tab;
    var clicked_tab;

    $('#tabs').tabs({
        show: function(event, ui) {
            current_tab = ui.index;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            clicked_tab = ui.index; //befor new one clicked
            MySelect(event, ui);
        }
    });

    function MySelect(event, ui) {
        //clicked_tab = ui.index //new clicked tab
        alert(current_tab + ' / ' + clicked_tab);
    }
});
```

Comment: This works perfect, thanks a lot! But I have a question: why do you write clicked_tab = ui.index; string twice? I have commented this string outside MySelect() function and it still works the same.

Comment: @DaneSoul Actually you don't have to.. http://jsfiddle.net/skram/tSCus/5/  Updated post.